# Search form slow show [html]

Tags: html, css

Anyone can help me create search form like this:

```
http://gledanjefilmova.net/
```

I know there is some elements in css but I forgot which was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create such an effect you add a transition property for the width and the color of the input field. When the field has focus you simply change the width and color.

```
.animated-input {
    background: #000;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    transition: width 1s, background 1s;
}

.animated-input:focus {
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4v0z4tLL/

Answer (score 0):

To add a slow motion effects to any element you have to use the transition property in css:

```
-webkit-transition: width 400ms ease-in;
transition: width 400ms ease-in;
```

for further information read:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp